# Tag rows with matching subset of column data

Tags: python, dataframe

Sorry if the title isn't clear. I don't know how to describe what I want to do. I'm looking to tag rows with class grouping with same set and subset of data cross columns. Starting with this data in a dataframe:

```
   group1  group2  group3  group4
1   Nan      X       Y       Z
2   Nan      X      Nan     Nan
3   Nan     Nan      Y       Z
4    X      Nan      Y      Nan
5    X       V       Y      Nan
6    V       V      Nan     Nan
7   Nan      X       Z       Y
```

I want to get to this:

```
    class  group1  group2  group3  group4
1    C1     Nan      X       Y       Z
2    C1     Nan      X      Nan     Nan
3    C1     Nan     Nan      Y       Z
4    C1      X      Nan      Y      Nan
5    C2      X       V       Y      Nan
6    C3      V       V      Nan     Nan
7    C4     Nan      X       Z       Y
```

The class has been grouped by the biggest common denominator. Column position does matter when looking at common patterns. I'm looking if there's a good why to do this without going through many loops.

edited for better example